# Apache2-mpm-prefork mpm-itk removed

Tags: 15.10, apache2.4

We re trying to upgrade a Ubuntu 12.04 server with apache2-mpm-prefork and libapache2-mpm-itk to either 15.10 or 16.04, however we are using an Ansible script.

The setup of the server fails because apache2-mpm-prefork package doesn't exist anymore, it seemingly has been removed from 15.10

What package do we use to have each website run on their own user account. We are planning to use PHP FPM